# X11 fowarding from Windows into Docker

Tags: docker, ssh, x11

Is is possible to do 'bridge' a X11 forward connection from a Docker to a Windows host by using the SSH connection?

On the Windows side I have Vagrant, VirtualBox and XMing installed. On the VirtualBox there is a CoreOS, serving the Docker images. What does work is adressing the display directly to the Windows machine by using the IP exposed by Vagrant (10.0.2.2):

```
docker run -e DISPLAY=10.0.2.2:0.0 someimage firefox
```

But this does not use the SSH tunnel, so it will only work in a local environment where the windows machine is reachable from the Docker container. From my understanding I would need to forward the display from within the Docker container to its outside, the CoreOS host and from there over to the SSH X11 entry-point.

Answer (score 0):

In your docker image, expose the port for ssh and make sure x11 is enabled in the sshd of the image. Then you can ssh into that via x11 enabled client. 
In order to ssh in from a remote machine, you need to add firewall permission for the port to which your Docker's port is mapped.

Bottom line: enable x11 in sshd of whatever your docker image is running on.
start docker with ssh port mapped to some port.
You're done here if only accessing from local Windows machine, else add firewall exception for the port to which you mapped docker's ssh daemon.